# Efficient code for grid design

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, grid

Recently I have been introduced to bootstrap and RWD. I have understood the whole idea but I cannot seem to master the grid system. I created a div container to make a fixed design. I want to use grids but I have lots of spaces in the webpage. Meaning it is something like this:

Header

about 10 lines of free space

Content / Content / Content

about 5 lines of free space

Content

How do I design my webpage like that using grids? I guess what I am asking is not how, but what is the efficient way to do it. I do not want my code to be messy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='span12'>HEADER</div>
    </div>

    <div class='row'>
        <div class='span4'>CONTENT</div>
        <div class='span4'>CONTENT</div> 
        <div class='span4'>CONTENT</div>
    </div>

    <div class='row'>
        <div class='span12'>CONTENT</div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

As for the lines of free space, add margins as needed

Comment: I was thinking maybe use empty rows until I reach the rows I want. How about that?

Comment: I definitely would not do that, mainly because it is ugly code, also, I don't think it would work because the height of these rows would be zero.
Why do you object to using margins?